# Get file name from URL using Lua

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

How do I get the file name from a **URL** using **Lua** string manipulations.

I have this url

`https://thisisarandomsite.com/some_dir/src/blah/blah/7fd34a0945b036685bbd6cc2583a5c30.jpg`

And I want to get the `7fd34a0945b036685bbd6cc2583a5c30.jpg`, it can be a random site so the site name is not static.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
local str = "https://thisisarandomsite.com/some_dir/src/blah/blah/7fd34a0945b036685bbd6cc2583a5c30.jpg"
local name = str:match( "([^/]+)$" )
```

You can customise the match pattern from [this guide](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

Comment: This pattern may be slightly simpler to understand: `".+/(.*)$"`.